# Problem with organizing tables on a television series

Tags: thesis, data, tables

I hope to ask for advice regarding how to best present my data for my thesis.

Currently I am working on a thesis that requires me to catalog instances of wicked women in a series, which includes dialogue, camera settings, aesthetics, etc. My problem is how to best show these instances as my data for my thesis.

I have four shows in total, so while the table method seems good to compare these instances, it's not very good for dialogue, as the dialogue is sometimes really long. And I can't just put episode title as an example because it's a descriptive kind of analysis.

Any advice would be nice!

Comment: When you say a table, do you mean of the raw data or a table with summary statistics of some kind?

Answer (score 4):

You might find it worthwhile to consider that most theses *do not* present large amounts of raw data in the body of the thesis. Raw data is often relegated to an appendix or even to an attached medium, such as a CD in a sleeve of the thesis cover. I say this because the (possibly large) samples of dialogue that are causing you difficulty seem to be raw data.

In the body of your thesis, you might, instead, present a table in which you have abstracted salient features of the dialogues or summarised the features of the dialogues that are important to the argument or line of enquiry that is central to your thesis topic. You could then refer the interested reader to the raw material if they wish to look at it.

When you think about how, exactly to lay out your tables, it is easy to make *the mistake of thinking about too narrow a range of options*. In your case, it sounds as if there are some categories of data that are very short (e.g., "camera settings"), and suitable for entry into a single column of a table, whereas other categories (e.g., the dialogue) contain extensive raw data. If you attempt to create a table of just four lines, in which each line represents a "show", then you will end up with something absurd. The dialogue will be squeezed into a column that is far too narrow to hold it, and the column of dialogue will (for each "show") extend far beyond the data for any of the other columns.

Instead of doing that, consider creating a table in which you might (or might not) have "columns", and where each show is represented by multiple lines. You could use formatting features like bold-ing, and background shading, to highlight the title of the show on a single line stretching the whole width of the table, and below that to have a line that has three or four columns (each with its own small bolded title) to show more succinct data. Without seeing your data, it's difficult to know, but here is an example (based on lots of assumptions!).

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your advice! I plan to put the data in the appendix and refer to it in short form in the thesis itself! I just don't know how to format the table in the appendix because putting the dialogue within the table makes it so stuffy.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a spreadsheet or data base file with the raw data AND the data itself is not subject to copyright (big question) you can consider storing the data on a site that allows viewing or (if you what to allow reuse) downloading.  There are many options for this, ranging from Google Sheets to Drop Box to your university's academic works site to ICPSR Open and more. I would suggest utilizing one of those. Social science faculty and in some cases life science faculty are likely to know about these options.

Answer (score -1):

When presenting data it is best to use visualisations through various kinds of plots, following the adage that a picture tells a-thousand words.  Indeed, in an academic paper or thesis, the actual data tables would usually be relegated to an appendix or supplementary material and the information in the data would be presented in plots with associated descriptive text.

Since you are undertaking a thesis at a university, you can begin by talking to your thesis supervisor, but you can also seek supplemetary advice from other academics who specialise in statistical analysis and visualisation of data.  I strongly recommend you go and talk to a statistician at your university to get help with your data and presentation of that data.  Most universities either have a statistics faculty or some kind of statistical consulting unit that can assist students.

---

**Associated issue/rant directed at my fellow academics:** For any research candidature that involves or anticipates empirical work involving data collection, analysis, or visualisation, the primary supervisor should always ensure that there is a statistician on the supervisory panel *from the start of the candidature*.  There is little that is more frustrating for academic statisticians than being asked to come in to help a problematic research candidature at the eleventh-hour to clean up messes or provide a *post mortem* for failed statistical methodology.  If you are a research candidate at a university, please talk to your supervisor as early as possible to see if you anticipate any empirical work, and if so, insist on having a statistician added to your supervisory panel from the start of your candidature (unless your primary supervisor is already a statistics expert).  If you are told this is unecessary, please direct your supervisor to me and I will try my best to set them straight.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your advice as well! I didn't think to ask the statistics department! I will do so once schools have opened! Thank you so much!

Comment: Many colleges do not have statisticians. However, they have many researchers who know how to organize data.